# Ruby on Rails undefined method `stringify_keys'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I am trying to create an event within a method of a separate controller (from the model I am creating).

```
def checkin
    #create a new event with todays date
    new_event = Event.new()
    new_event[:date] = todays_date(current_merchant)
    @event = current_merchant.events.create(new_event)
end
```

I get this error: 
`undefined method`stringify_keys'`

I have a method that generates todays date, but I don't believe that is the issue since I've tested it with an actual date and still get the same stringify error.

Date is an attribute, here is my schema:

```
  create_table "events", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.date     "date"
    t.integer  "age"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "merchant_id"
    t.string   "photo"
  end
```

I've tried using `new_event.date` but get the same error. 
The error gets highlighted in terminal on the following line:

@event = current_merchant.events.create(new_event)

The error that shows up in console is the following:

```
(0.3ms)  BEGIN
(0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4495ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `stringify_keys' for #<Event:0x007f7f8f2a26f8>):
  app/controllers/merchants_controller.rb:25:in `checkin'


  Rendered /Users/steclaudinodaffara/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/steclaudinodaffara/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered /Users/steclaudinodaffara/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/steclaudinodaffara/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (14.5ms)
```

Comment: date must be an attribute of Event model, `new_event.date = todays_date(current_merchant)`

Comment: Date is an attribute. And when I run it as date.event,m, I get the same stringify error

Comment: Share the full server log generated when you get this error. Add it in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the `checkin` method as below:

```
def checkin
    params = ActionController::Parameters.new({:event => {date: todays_date(current_merchant}})
    @event = current_merchant.events.create(params.require(:event).permit(:date)))
end
```

You were trying to create an associated `event record` for `current_merchant` by passing an instance of `Event` model to create method. `create` method expects `Hash` as an argument which is why you get the error.

Comment: This was my initial solution, and it removes the stringify error BUT the date is not being saved the the event.

Comment: I see that you are using Rails 4.0.4, you would need to white list the attributes that you would like to be saved.

Comment: What is "white list"?

Comment: Assuming that `checkin` method is in `EventsController`. See if you have a method name `event_params` in it. Share the code of that method in question.

Comment: The checkin method is not in events controller, it is in merchants controller